# Close Bootstrap modal using jQuery in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use Bootstrap modal inside React. I have successfully opened a modal. For closing the modal programatically, I am using the below code.

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
```

The code is written inside the onClick event of a button. When I click the button, I am getting the error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).modal is not a function`

I have imported Bootstrap and jQuery as below.

```
import 'bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

How to fix this? How can I use jQuery inside React to close the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `react-bootstrap` and try to avoid JQuery while working with React. Because JQuery is at a bit different level than React internals, if I can put it this way.

In this example you can see how it can be handled within component state to `show` modal:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live